# Meaning of a phrase or word spoken in an Irish film

Tags: meaning

What does it mean when someone says "I don't want to live in a kip like this when I get married"?

Comment: Google has it as Irish slang. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

[kip](https://www.irelandbeforeyoudie.com/irish-slang-top-80-most-used-expressions/) is Irish slang for

> A dump of a place

Hence, "I don't want to live in a horrible place like this when I marry."

Comment: Answering a bad post with a good answer is .. well ... not helping the site. Just saying.